Can I Control a Betaflight Drone Using MSP Instead of CRSF?
I'm new to drones and currently working on a project involving a drone equipped with Betaflight firmware. Right now, the drone is controlled by an ELRS module using the CRSF protocol. However, I would like to remove the ELRS receiver from serial_rx port and instead connect a Raspberry Pi (or Arduino) to the drone’s serial port, which I have configured for MSP in Betaflight Configurator.
My goal is to send MSP_SET_RAW_RC  packets from the Raspberry Pi to control the drone. I’ve noticed traces of MSP in the receiver section of Betaflight Configurator, but I’m unsure if this will fully allow me to control the drone using MSP in place of the ELRS receiver.

Can anyone clarify if Betaflight supports controlling the drone via MSP in this way? Is it possible to replace the ELRS receiver with an MSP connection for flight control?
Thanks in advance!
